# update table multiplied with exchange rate

Tags: kdb

I have two tables, i need to check if the currencyStr from table1 is present in table2 and update the qty with the corresponding exchangeRate.

```
table1:([] qty: 100 200 150 130 200 230 300; currencyStr: ("USD"; "EUR"; "GBP"; "JPY"; "AUD"; "USD"; "GBP"))
table2:([] currencyStr: ("USD"; "EUR"; "GBP"; "AUD"; "JPY"); exchangeRate: (1.0; 0.85; 0.75; 0.95; 0.5))
```

| qty |
| --- |
| 100 |
| 170 |
| 112.5 |
| 65 |
| 190 |
| 225 |
| 300 |

Comment: Did you try looking at the official documentation on joins? https://code.kx.com/q/basics/joins/ or https://code.kx.com/q4m3/9_Queries_q-sql/#99-joins ?

Answer (score 3):

Using `lj` left join:

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/lj/

```
delete exchangeRate from update qty*1f^exchangeRate from table1 lj `currencyStr xkey table2
qty   currencyStr
-----------------
100   "USD"
170   "EUR"
112.5 "GBP"
65    "JPY"
190   "AUD"
230   "USD"
225   "GBP"
```

Or using `!` to perform dictionary lookup:

```
update qty*1f^(exec currencyStr!exchangeRate from table2) currencyStr from  table1
qty   currencyStr
-----------------
100   "USD"
170   "EUR"
112.5 "GBP"
65    "JPY"
190   "AUD"
230   "USD"
225   "GBP"
```

`1f^` is important **if you want** to fill/replace any failed lookups with `1f` rather than a null `0Nf` which would have updated your `qty` to null also.

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/fill/